# How to use mobile wifi and data connection simultaneously for different purposes in android app

Tags: android, wifi, data-connections

I am working on a research task and I need to use wifi and mobile data connection simultaneously for different tasks in an Android app. Is it possible? if yes then how? Any suggestions for work-around are also appreciated.

Comment: hey have u found any solution?

Comment: no .. it is not possible with current android policy. I then modified the android kernel and hacked the policy code to allow both services activated at the same time.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429190/how-wifi-and-mobile-data-both-work-simultaneously-in-android-for-obd2-device

Comment: @KanwarSaad Have you found any solution without changing the kernel? I know that since Android 6 it is possible to have both connections simultaneously.

Comment: yes i tried with android 6. They have introduced few APIs to enable both connections simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but straight answer is no.

Android automatically changes to WiFi when available because it is faster.

Sorry

There maybe a way if you root your device