# Multipath TCP on Android / IPhone

Tags: android, ios, tcp, wifi, cell

I have a device that creates a WiFi network that is not connected to the internet.  This device hosts a website using IIS.  To operate the device, a smartphone connects to the WiFi and browses the site.  The smartphone needs to get data from an api (internet) and pass it to the website on the device.

I have tried to remove the default gateway setting from the DHCP server on the local WiFi, but this is not permitted on the device.

I have not been able to find an app that will allow both WiFi and Cellular data to be used simultaneously.

If I were to allow the device to connect to a hot spot that the smartphone creates, the smart phone cannot access the device's WAP.

The next option I'm considering is to toggle the WiFi Off and On during the process.

I'm wondering if anyone has another solution to this issue?

Comment: Why are you calling that multipath tcp? Your phone does not have simultanous wifi and mobile connection. Thats what you want.

Comment: Understood;  In light of my phone's limitations, I am curios if there is another solution that I haven't considered.

Comment: In general, this is an issue that needs to be fixed on your wifi router level, not phone level. Your WiFi network should allow internet connectivity by routing properly to your IIS and internet provider properly. That being said, there are cases where hardware devices that are controlled through WiFi providing no option to connect to external internet. this may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429190/how-wifi-and-mobile-data-both-work-simultaneously-in-android-for-obd2-device