# Android 7.1 turn on/off mobile data

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-7.1-nougat, cellular-network

I'm writing software that works with some data in internet over cellular data and prints invoice through the WiFi to HP printer using direct print. I'm not using routers or other network devices.
so as i know new android 7.1 has a feature that doesn't connects to a network that has no access to the internet. when I disable cellular data it connects to wifi and prints it without any problem.

is there any solution for this situation. so when I connect to wifi without internet it will switch to a wifi no matter what.

Comment: I think here the question is, is there a way to turn off mobile data programmatically in Android 7?

Comment: yes there is a way to turn it on off but in 7.1 (or maybe in older versions) there is a restriction that only system apps can do it.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about the restriction. I know in older versions is allowed, but in Android 5+ it's blocked :(

Comment: So you don't need to disable data, just enable the WIFI connexion : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered a similar question, which you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54019496/783707)

To summarize, you need to implement these:

1. Network callback for WiFi network.
2. Request a network using [ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#requestNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent))
3. Then when callback is received, use [Network.openConnection()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#openConnection(java.net.URL)) to make an HTTP request